# Select only a type of object inside a list python

Tags: python-3.x, list, oop, any, isinstance

I have a list of 2 types of customers classic customer and hipsters. I have a function associated to these classes which tells me if they are in budget. I would like to know if it still exist a hipster which is in budget.
Something like, however the isinstance() return me a boolean.

```
any(isinstance(x, HipsterRecurrent).is_in_budget() for x in self.RecurrentCustomersList)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mre] of your code.

Comment: I succeed ! I did any(isinstance(x, HipsterRecurrent) x.is_in_budget() == True for x in self.RecurrentCustomersList)

Answer (score 0):

I succeed ! I did any(isinstance(x, HipsterRecurrent) and x.is_in_budget() == True for x in self.RecurrentCustomersList)